# Drupal 8: How to create accordion View with table inside?

Tags: views, 8, navigation

I'm trying to generate a accordion grouped by year. I have used [Accordion](https://www.drupal.org/node/2691019) module for this. **It is giving accordion which is fine but I want data inside accordion in tabular format. For ex:**

[image]

**Table header is getting repeated in accordion. I want a single header for table. How to achieve this?**

@EDIT

**How to modify views.accordion-view.html.twig file so that row.content organized itself in tabular format as described in above image.**

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a views_accordion set of rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_accordion_view()
 */
#}
{% if title %}
  <h3 class="js-views-accodion-group-header">{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  {# A div wrapping the row content is required for the accordion to work #}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you or anyone else can't find the answer, the alternative would be to create your own custom accordion.

Comment: I have gone through the code of `views.accordion-view.html.twig` of views accordion module. how can I modify its template file so that fields will organize themselves in tabular format.